# Perl finding input file

Tags: perl

In perl I need to print all the chosen files:

```
./print.pl 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
```

the ARGV is 2 and I can print them.But then I write the command like:

```
./print.pl <1.txt 2.txt
```

when I run in this way the output is 2.txt only and the ARGV is 0.How can I detected <1.txt as a input file?

the file name is 1.txt, '<' is used to put 1.txt into the code.

Comment: `<` causes the shell to redirect the contents of `1.txt` to `STDIN` for the command `print.pl` and pass `2.txt` as the only element in `@ARGV`

Comment: Is `<1.txt` really the filename? Including the leading `<`? Or do you want to call `print.pl` with one file that comes from stdin and another one that is given as a filename?

Comment: And this is one reason why you _always_ use a 3 arg open!

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what you're asking. Please at least show your Perl code.

Comment: If your filename is really `1.txt` and you pipe its content into `print.pl` by means of shell metacharacter `<`, then there's no way. Your script cannot figure out where that input comes from – it's just the script's STDIN.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you really have a file name that starts with `<`, put the filename in quotes when you send it in as an argument.

This prints just the file name:

```
perl -E 'say $ARGV[0]' "<1.txt"
<1.txt
```

This small script prints out the file's contents:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

for (@ARGV){
    open my $fh, '<', $_ or die $!;
    print <$fh>;
}
```

Example:

```
perl script.pl "<1.txt"
a
b
c
```